# Getting IndexError: list index out of range from arcpy.mapping.ListLayers() in Python Window of ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling, python-window, indexerror

i want to turn on label using arcpy, i use current mxd and my mxd path in my script and my layers also active in the current MXD, but it give me this eror, can somebody help me?

here the script i used :

```
import arcpy

... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\P51\Desktop\testingLABEL.mxd") 

... df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]

... layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "point10", df)[0] 

... layer.showLabels = True
```

and this is the eror :

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 4, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

here is the screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this from the Python Window then instead of using:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\P51\Desktop\testingLABEL.mxd")
```

I think you should use:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
```

My suspicion is that the layer named `point10` has been added to your current map (which you presumably opened using `C:\Users\P51\Desktop\testingLABEL.mxd`) after you created your MapDocument object named `mxd`.

The IndexError seems to be saying that ArcPy cannot find a layer named `point10` in the MapDocument object named `mxd`.

---

As an aside there is never a need to `import arcpy` in the Python Window of ArcMap.  That is done automatically when the Python Window is opened.

Comment: oke thats great, its works, so the problem is in r"C:\Users\P51\Desktop\testingLABEL.mxd" and replace with "current", thanks anyway for your help